# How can I parse the full name from an email using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to extract information from email messages. I have a list of .eml files and have a ruby program to read in each message, then print the output.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'mail'
basedir = '.'
files = Dir.glob("*.eml")
files.each do |i|
  mail = Mail.read(i)
  puts "filename: #{i}"
  puts "from: #{mail.from}"
  puts "to: #{mail.to}"
end
```

It works, but I'm trying to get the full name from the email addresses as well. So instead of just `"bobloblaw@example.com"` I'm trying to get `"<Bob Loblaw> bobloblaw@example.com"`.

Comment: *So instead of just "bobloblaw@example.com" I'm trying to get " bobloblaw@example.com"* - Your expectation and output are the same, what's your issue?

Comment: Ugh! I can't even use StackOverflow properly yet! Yes, they were the same. I've used the backticks to escape the emails I'm getting and the ones I would like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `display_names` property like so:

```
mail[:from].display_names.first
mail[:to].display_names.first
```

Note that `display_names` is an array as a message can have more than one recipient. The code above would get you the first name.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the `header` to retrieve this information.

```
mail.header[:from].formatted
```

See [`common_address.rb`](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb) for more methods.